# Prove the $3^n < n!$ for all $n > 6$

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm trying to use induction to prove this.  I'm sure it's a simple proof, but I can't seem to get over the first few steps.  Any help?

Allow $P(n)=3^n<n!$

Base Case:

$P(7) = 3^7<7! \rightarrow$ True.

Induction:

Assume $P(k) = 3^k<k!$

Now we must prove $P(k+1)$.  Here's where I'm lost.  If I'm adding a +1 to the exponent on the LHS, where would I add it to the factorial on the RHS?

Comment: Hint: $3^{k+1}=3^k\cdot 3.$

Comment: So I multiply the RHS by 3?

Comment: You are **multiplying** the left by $3$. You are multiplying the right by $n+1$.  If the right side was ahead, and $n\ge 2$, it stays ahead.

Comment: Take the ratio:
$$
\varphi(k)=\frac{3^k}{k!}\\
\varphi(k+1)=\frac{3^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}=\varphi(k)\frac{3}{k+1}
$$
Obviously 
$$
\frac{3}{k+1}<1 \ \forall \ k>2
$$

Comment: " If I'm adding a +1 to the exponent on the LHS".  What does "adding a $+1$ to an exponent *mean*?  It means multiplying by the base. So do that.  $3^{k+1} = 3\times 3^k$.  Now if $3^k < k!$ that means $3\times 3^k < 3\times k!$.

Answer (score 1):

The key to induction proofs is finding a way to work your induction hypothesis into the "$k+1$" case.

We want to show $3^{k+1} < (k+1)!$. Since you know $3^k < k!$, we need to keep an eye out for a factor of $3^k$. Let's just start with the lefthand side of the "$k+1$" case and see what we can do.
$$
\begin{align*}
3^{k+1} &= 3 \cdot 3^k\\
&< 3 \cdot k! && \text{(inductive hypothesis)}\\
&< (k+1) \cdot k! && \text{(since k > 2)}\\
&= (k+1)!
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. The rest of the comments/answers have interpreted it in one way, but my answer to the question:

> Here's where I'm lost. If I'm adding a +1 to the exponent on the LHS, where would I add it to the factorial on the RHS?

Is that the RHS will look like $(k+1)!$. I'm not sure why you might have thought otherwise? Did you think it might be $k! + 1$? Remember that you are inducting **on $k$**. So wherever you saw a $n$ you'd replace it with $k+1$.

If this was indeed the confusion you had it would be really really worth it to make sure you understand induction better (and maybe even refresh yourself on the definition of a function?). I can write up a loose description of induction that might help you if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Base case:
$$n = 7 \to {3^7} < 7! \to 2187 < 5040\;\;True
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamOBaiabg2
% da9iaaiEdacqGHsgIRcaaIZaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaI3aaaaOGaeyiz
% ImQaaG4naiaacgcacqGHsgIRcaaIYaGaaGymaiaaiIdacaaI3aGaey
% izImQaaGynaiaaicdacaaI0aGaaGimaiaaysW7caaMe8Uaamivaiaa
% dkhacaWG1bGaamyzaaaa!4FB5!
$$
Inductive Assumption: Assume
$${3^k} < k!\;\;is\;true\;for\;any\;k \ge 7
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaG4mamaaCa
% aaleqabaGaam4AaaaakiabgsMiJkaadUgacaGGHaGaaGjbVlaaysW7
% caWGPbGaam4CaiaaysW7caWG0bGaamOCaiaadwhacaWGLbGaaGjbVl
% aadAgacaWGVbGaamOCaiaaysW7caWGHbGaamOBaiaadMhacaaMe8Ua
% am4Aaiabg6da+iaaiEdaaaa!527F!
$$
Now, we have to show:
$$\;{3^{k + 1}} < (k + 1)!\;\;is\;true\;too.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaGjbVlaaio
% dadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgacqGHRaWkcaaIXaaaaOGaeyizImQaaiik
% aiaadUgacqGHRaWkcaaIXaGaaiykaiaacgcacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaadM
% gacaWGZbGaaGjbVlaadshacaWGYbGaamyDaiaadwgacaaMe8UaamiD
% aiaad+gacaWGVbGaaiOlaaaa!50B2!
$$
Lets start:
$${3^k} < k! \to 3 \times {3^k} < 3 \times k! \to {3^{k + 1}} < 3 \times k!\;\;\;(A)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaG4mamaaCa
% aaleqabaGaam4AaaaakiabgsMiJkaadUgacaGGHaGaeyOKH4QaaG4m
% aiabgEna0kaaiodadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgaaaGccqGHKjYOcaaIZa
% Gaey41aqRaam4AaiaacgcacqGHsgIRcaaIZaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWG
% RbGaey4kaSIaaGymaaaakiabgsMiJkaaiodacqGHxdaTcaWGRbGaai
% yiaiaaysW7caaMe8UaaGjbVlaacIcacaWGbbGaaiykaaaa!5A26!
$$
On the other hand:
$$k \ge 7 \to 7 \le k \to 8 \le k + 1 \to 3 < 8 \le k + 1 \to 3 < k + 1\;
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam4Aaiabg6
% da+iaaiEdacqGHsgIRcaaI3aGaeyipaWJaam4AaiabgkziUkaaiIda
% cqGH8aapcaWGRbGaey4kaSIaaGymaiabgkziUkaaiodacqGH8aapca
% aI4aGaeyipaWJaam4AaiabgUcaRiaaigdacqGHsgIRcaaIZaGaeyip
% aWJaam4AaiabgUcaRiaaigdacaaMe8oaaa!5347!
$$
$$ \times k! \to 3 \times k! < (k + 1) \times k!\;\;\;(B)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaey41aqRaam
% 4AaiaacgcacqGHsgIRcaaIZaGaey41aqRaam4AaiaacgcacqGH8aap
% caGGOaGaam4AaiabgUcaRiaaigdacaGGPaGaey41aqRaam4Aaiaacg
% cacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caGGOaGaamOqaiaacMcaaaa!4F42!
$$
$$A,\;B \to \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{{3^{k + 1}} < 3 \times k!\quad \;\;\;\;\;\;}\\{3 \times k! < (k + 1) \times k!}\end{array}} \right. \to {3^{k + 1}} < (k + 1) \times k! \to {3^{k + 1}} < (k + 1)!
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyqaiaacY
% cacaaMe8UaamOqaiabgkziUoaaceaabaqbaeqabiqaaaqaaiaaioda
% daahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgacqGHRaWkcaaIXaaaaOGaeyizImQaaG4mai
% abgEna0kaadUgacaGGHaGaaGzbVlaaysW7caaMe8UaaGjbVlaaysW7
% caaMe8UaaGjbVdqaaiaaiodacqGHxdaTcaWGRbGaaiyiaiabgYda8i
% aacIcacaWGRbGaey4kaSIaaGymaiaacMcacqGHxdaTcaWGRbGaaiyi
% aaaaaiaawUhaaiabgkziUkaaiodadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgacqGHRa
% WkcaaIXaaaaOGaeyipaWJaaiikaiaadUgacqGHRaWkcaaIXaGaaiyk
% aiabgEna0kaadUgacaGGHaGaeyOKH4QaaG4mamaaCaaaleqabaGaam
% 4AaiabgUcaRiaaigdaaaGccqGH8aapcaGGOaGaam4AaiabgUcaRiaa
% igdacaGGPaGaaiyiaaaa!773C!
$$
So, we proved:
$${3^n} < n!\;\;for\;any\;n \ge 7
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaG4mamaaCa
% aaleqabaGaamOBaaaakiabgsMiJkaad6gacaGGHaGaaGjbVlaaysW7
% caWGMbGaam4BaiaadkhacaaMe8Uaamyyaiaad6gacaWG5bGaaGjbVl
% aad6gacqGHLjYScaaI3aaaaa!4A72!
$$

Answer (score 0):

Single line:

If $3^k < k!$ and $k>6$ then $3^{k+1} = 3\times 3^k < 3\times k!  < (k+1)\times k! = (k+1)!$

(As $n > 6$ we can assume than $k>6$ and therefor $k+1 > 7 > 3$)

=======================================

> If I'm adding a +1 to the exponent on the LHS, where would I add it to the factorial on the RHS?

What does "adding a $+1$ to an exponent" *mean*?

It means multiplying by the base.

So do that.

$3^{k+1} = 3\times 3^k$.

Now if $3^k < k!$ that means $3\times 3^k < 3\times k!$

> where would I add it to the factorial on the RHS?

well that means multiplying the factorial by $k+1$.

So $(k+1)! = k! \times (k+1)$.

Now you have to compare $3\times k!$ to $k! \times (k+1)$ and the rest is obvious.

.....

$3\times k! < (k+1)\times k!$ so long as $k + 1 > 3$ or $k > 2$.  And as $k > 6$ we have that.

.....

So

$3^{k+1}\color{tan}=$

> $\color{red}{3\times 3^k<3\times k! < (k+1)\times k!}$

$\color{tan}= (k+1)!$